# How to save image from drawable as png in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

Problem:

I can't save image from drawable as png in android.

Code:

```
 Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
 eventsList.get(position).getEvent_image());

            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/png");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                    b, "imagePath", null);
            if (!SampleUtil.isNullOrEmpty(path)) {
                /*Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);*/
                selectedImage = path;
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

**step 1. get your bitmap in to drawable obje like this**

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

**step 2 save in your storage like this**

```
 String extStorageDirectory =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "launcher.PNG");
    try {
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Don't forget to add** `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.`